# Chrome Extension Message Passing Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to pass a message from my background page to a content script yet I get this error(from the console):

**Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.**

Here is my code : ***//content script:***

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({name:"connection"});
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
alert('I never get to see this message...');
 });
});
```

And in background.js I first create a tab that has a content script and then once the tab is made I try to connect to it's content script

***//background.js***

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://myextension.uphero.com/"},function(tab){
var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tab.id,{name:"connection"});
console.log('port is :' +port.name);
console.log(port.onMessage);
port.postMessage({msg:"whatever"});
  });
```

Now I know that the problem isn't in manifest.json or anything like that (the content script is defined ok , it's just the port and connecting that are having problem). Would really appreciate any help ...

Comment: Do you know the meaning of async? Have you also tried to visualise what happens when your script runs? Doing that will lead to the answer.

Comment: How about elaborating a little ? As for the ansync - as far as I know using a callback function the order should be clear - first create the tab , then when you're finished carry on to the callback(and connect to the port etc).

Comment: Just to explain where I'm coming from , in jQuery for example if you write :   $('#element').fadeIn('slow', function() {  
        // callback function  
    });  Then it's obvious that the code first fades in the element and only afterwards proceeds to execute the callback . That is the behavior I am expecting when I use tabs.create and pass it a callback that connects to it's script . So unless I'm missing something you haven't really answered anything.

Comment: Hint: When `create`'s callback is called, the tab has been *created*. The page might not have loaded yet, so the content script isn't even activated when the callback of `create` is triggered. Hint 2: In both snippets, you're trying to connect to a port. Certainly, one of them (the content script one) will never succeed, because the other side (the background page) doesn't define an event listener to `chrome.extension.onConnect`

Comment: Thanks Rob I think this will help